# How to save values of x for condition below

Tags: matlab

How to save values of x for condition below and assign y to them to find its length

```
    for i=1:100
    n=1;
    x(i)=rand
    if x>0.5
    y=x;
    end
    length(y)
    end
```

Comment: `x=rand(1,100); y=x(x>0.5);  length(y)`   ?

Comment: thanks very useful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop here. Do the following:

```
x = rand(1,100); %Storing all values at once
y = x(x>0.5);    %Storing values of x greater than 0.5 in y
length(y)        %Finding the length of y
```

**Suggested reading:**

 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  [***Matrix Indexing in MATLAB***

by Steve Eddins and Loren Shure (MathWorks)](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Comment: Apart from that, always avoid using `i` and `j` as variables names. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab